# How to disable all email notifications included "Urgent service advisories" from firebase console?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I need to disable all notifications from firebase console (also "Urgent service advisories"). In our project a lot of users, but they do not need alerts from Crashlytics.

I found only two notification settings:

1) Firebase alerts, that includes urgent notifications I need to disable!
[image]

2) Velocity alert settings. But there is just velocity, this setting also not disable all notifications.
[image]

Any suggestions how to disable all notifications for current users in project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try making a custom role if you go to Settings>Users and permissions>Advanced permissions settings, and removing this role "cloudnotifications.activities.list". If that doesn't do it, you'll just have to make an email filter and blacklist the notifier manually.
2. If you click the notification bell in the Firebase Console, and go to settings, you can click into your Project, and disable Velocity Alerts from the Crashlytics section.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps

[image: select notification]

1. Click notification in firebase
2. Settings
3. Select your projects in Feature alerts box
4. You can uncheck any feature notification or email